# Removing XSS vulnerability from php pages

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xss

I have a public search page from where public / user can search for record stored in Mysql database and then click on the link generated by the page to open details of the selected record in the details page. But it shows XSS Vulnerability in the page:

> HTTP Header input Referer was set to javascript:prompt(984663);
>
> The input is reflected inside A tag href parameter, a FORM tag action
>   parameter or (I) FRAME src parameter.

i have put the **htmlentities()** before echoing each value from the target page also from the page who is **referring** the target page?
Is there any good way to make both the pages safe from this attack?

code snippet of my page which is a referrer looks like this:

```
<a target="_new" href="<?php echo(htmlentities(SG::getBaseUrl())); ?>/reports/<?php echo(intval($c['sno'])); ?>/caseFullDtlByCaseSno.php" title="Click here to view full details of this case">
            <?php echo(htmlentities($c['first_party']).' V/S '.htmlentities($c['second_party'])); ?>
            </a>
```

How to remove the following type of XSS vulnerability from my page?

Comment: It seems `SG::getBaseUrl()` uses the Referer header instead of the Host header, or better, a configurable env variable that doesn't depend on input at all.

Comment: @Paulpro SG::getBaseUrl() method containing the following code:

Comment: public static function getBaseUrl(){
   try{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
     return 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
     } 
    else {
     return 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
     }
    }catch(Exception $exc){
     $this->sgVar = $exc->getMessage();  
     return false;
     }
   }

Comment: Does the Referer header affect `$c['sno']`?

Comment: @Paulpro no not actually, because $c['sno'] is an integer value and comes from database without user interaction....

Comment: _“But it shows XSS Vulnerability in the page”_ - where, and who/what is “it”? Are you running some sort of test suite/tool to check against XSS automatically, is this the browser itself detecting this, …? Did you actually see a prompt containing `984663` when you open the page? Did you find it in the HTML source code?

Comment: @CBroe i am testing the web pages using the Acunetix Scanning tool. and it shows the xss vulnerability in the page. but when i try to access the url produced by the Acunetix tool, it shows error 404 page not found....

Comment: So was it able to successfully insert code into our 404 page then, or where does the actual issue manifest?

Comment: GET /FakeUrl HTTP/1.1
**Referer: javascript:prompt(941059);**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.63 Safari/537.36
Cookie: PHPSESSID=reaeff2kh173eqrei576m9o49s
Host: www.phcc.com
Connection: Keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: */*

Comment: @CBroe i have just copied these from the tool where it shows that Referrer injection could be possible...

Comment: Ok I have tested the XSS by passing javascript:prompt(941059); in the Referer header but got nothing / no prompt .. It means i don't need to worry about this anymore.... :)

Comment: Do you get a 404 page? Have you checked whether the JavaScript appears anywhere on the page. It could be event-driven or browser dependent so a prompt not appearing for you doesn't mean it's safe.

Comment: @fgb no, there is no javascript shown in the page, i have checked the page.